# Non anonymous callback function with parameters called by standard function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This example is to only to provide better picture to the nature of the problem.

The function `setTimeout(callback, timeMs)` is a standard. Hot to pass arguments to the callback function?

```
function handleRequestCB(request, response)
{
    console.log("Request Received");
    if (request.method === 'GET') 
    {
        console.log(request.url);
    }
    setTimeout(doResponse(response), 2000);//I know I cant pass arguments!
}



function doResponse(response)
{
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(htmlFile);
    response.end(); 
}
```

How to call this non anonymous function `doResponse()` from `setTimeout` and passing argument in the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, `setTimeout` won't accept a parameter in `callback`. But you can pass an anonymous function, calling your function. So you can just do the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    doResponse(response);    
}, 2000);
```

Yeah, that's tricky. Note that some browsers also [accept a 3rd parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) that is a parameter, eg:

```
setTimeout(doResponse(), 2000, response);
```

I wouldn't recommand it, as it is not supported in IE9 and earlier.

Comment: This is so obvious! How come I didn't think of it? Newbies :D

Comment: @Hairi Have a look to [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), it provides some detailled examples of what I explained shorter in my answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can actually pass some parameters. Try that:

```
setTimeout(function(a){console.log(a)}.bind(null,"sss"),1000)
```